# Based on user password, they can only edit certain row in the mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 table which is:

```
pengguna                            perak
username|password                   pkg    |kodsk
123     |123                        ayer   |a1233
abc     |abc                        bagan  |b1234
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

session_start();
include("connections.php");

try{

    $query = "SELECT * FROM pengguna INNER JOIN perak ON pengguna.pkg=perak";

    $data = $connect->query($query);

    echo '<table width="70%" border="5" cellpading="1" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
                 <th>BIL</th>
                 <th>PKG</th>
                 <th>KOD SEKOLAH</th>
                 <th>NAMA SEKOLAH</th>
                 <th>TAHUN OPERASI</th>
                 <th>MAKMAL</th>
                 <th>CATATAN</th>
                 <th>BIL. MURID</th>
                 <th>AGIHAN NETBOOK</th> 
            </tr>';

    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row["bil"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["pkg"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["kodsk"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["namask"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["tahun"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["makmal"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["catatan"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["murid"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["netbook"].'</td>
              </tr>';
    }


}

catch(PDOException $error){

$error->getMessage();
}


?>
```

How do i let the user with password 123 can only see and edit only row for ayer while user with password abc can only see and edit row bagan only ?

Comment: Why do you have passwords in the `username` column? And what happens if two different users choose the same password? You should do access control by username, not by password.

Comment: from login how do can i let the user can view and edit certain row only ?

Comment: When they login you set a session variable to the username. Then when querying the database, you use `WHERE` to limit them to the rows matching their username.

Comment: i've done that but failed, can u check my code where is fail part ?

Comment: There's nothing that relates the two tables to each other, the `JOIN` doesn't make sense.

Comment: It should be `ON pengguna.someCol = perak.someOtherCol`, where the columns are the ones that are the same between the two tables and relate them.

Comment: Security isn't something that should be done by beginners, there are too many ways to make mistakes. You need to find an experienced programmer to do this for you.

Comment: i've edit as u say sir, but when i login with username and password it still show all the data. If can i want the 1st user only see the 1st row only.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table that says which packages each user can access

```
userpkg
username    pkg
123         ayer
abc         bagan
```

Then you can join the tables.

```
SELECT perak.*
FROM perak 
JOIN userpkg ON perak.pkg = userpkg.pkg
WHERE userpkg.username = '$username'
```

where `$username` comes from a session variable set when the user logs in.

You'll need to do similar checks on `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: This work ? login.php
<form action="session.php" method="post">
     <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="KBR2xN6.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
     </div>

     <div class="container">
      <label><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="name" required>
      <br />

      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pass" required>

      <button type="submit">Login</button>
      <button type="reset" class="cancelbtn">Reset</button>

Comment: this is session.php:
session_start();
include('connections.php');

$username = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM pengguna WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' ";
$result = $connect->query($sql);

if($result->rowcount()>0){
 foreach($result AS $data){
  $_SESSION['name'] = $data['name'];
  $_SESSION['pass'] = $data['pass'];
  
 echo "<script>alert('Login Success');
   window.location.href='view.php';
   </script>";
 }
}
 
else {
 echo "<script>alert('Login Failed');
   window.location.href='login.php';
   </script>";

Comment: Don't put code in comments, it's unreadable without formatting. Either edit the question or post a new question.

Comment: You should be using usernames, not passwords, as the foreign key in other tables. Passwords should only be used for authentication, and they should be hashed.